# ASP.NET DataContext issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datacontext

I'm calling the ExecuteQuery method of my DataContext object. I expect a String and an Integer for each row as a result but all my values are nothing and 0 when I run the ToList function. All my results should be different strings and numbers. My query runs perfectly if I run it directly, but ExecuteQuery returns garbage instead of valid results. What can be the cause of this?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
public function something as List(of Pair(of String, Integer))
            Dim c As TTDataContext = ContextFactory.CreateDataContext()
            Dim startValueLen = CStr(StartValue).Length
            Dim query As String = "select top " & CStr(Limit) & " case " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '0000%' then SUBSTRING(WONum, 5, Len(WONum) - 4) " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '000%' then SUBSTRING(WONum, 4, Len(WONum) - 3) " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '00%' then SUBSTRING(WONum, 3, Len(WONum) - 2) " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '0%' then SUBSTRING(WONum, 2, Len(WONum) - 1) " &
                                                                   " else WONum " &
                                                                   " end as retVal, " &
                                                                   " case " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '0000%' then 1 " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '000%' then 2 " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '00%' then 3 " &
                                                                   " when WONum like '0%' then 4 " &
                                                                   " else LEN(WONum) " &
                                                                   " end as retLen " &
                                                                   " from TblWorkOrder " &
                                                                   " where CompanyID = " & CStr(CompanyID) & " and LEN(WONum) >= " & CStr(startValueLen) & " and (WONum > '" & CStr(StartValue) & "' or LEN(WONum) > " & CStr(startValueLen) & ") " &
                                                                   " order by retLen, retVal"
            Dim temp = c.ExecuteQuery(Of Pair(Of String, Integer))(query)
            Return temp.ToList
End Function
```

Comment: perhaps show us some code? How do you expect me to answer this???

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I've postet a very simple code, because my query is of 1500 characters approx.

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag selection. This would have been the only question on stack overflow tagged `vb`, out of more than 3 million. That should be a **huge** indicator that something is wrong. Instead, use a more specific tag, like vb.net, vbscript, vb6, or vba

Comment: Also: do you know what an sql injection vulnerability is? It looks like it's past time you learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that my Pair class had a First and a Second property and I didn't return my results as First and as second. So the solution for the problem is to return the first value as First and the second value as Second instead of retVal and retLen.